# HTML string as a JSON output using C#

Tags: c#, html, json

HTML string as a JSON output using C#.

I want to replace every instance of ", that is between HTML wrapper < and > with ', while converting to JSON. At the same time if it has text with " quote then it should not be replaced with the ' quote. E.g. `"since the 1500s"`

Code - Which is replacing all " to ' quotes

```
public string Content
{
    get
    {
       return _content;
    }
    set
    {
       if (value != null)
       {
           this._content = this._content.Replace("\"", "'");     
       }
     }
}
```

I am getting string in this form, from my View.

```
E.g.  model.Content = "<p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing <span id= "#" ids= "#" display= "inline" ></ span > and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever "since the 1500s".<br></p>";
```

I am using JsonConvert.SerializeObject

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
```

Expected string - All double quotes in the HTML tags should be converted into single quote but the text quotes should be as it is using C#

```
 "content": "<p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b> is simply dummy <i>text </i>of the printing&nbsp;<span id='#' ids='#' display='inline'></span> and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever \"since the 1500s\".</p>",
```

Comment: Can you provide more information, please. Why should double quotes become single quotes, for example? How are you converting it to JSON, etc?

Comment: Is a method of c# returning this output? please more info

Comment: Are you using JSON.NET or JavaScriptSerializer or any other Serializer?

Comment: @Jack it would be useful to update your question with the code, otherwise that is just a mess. ps also try to put some effort into formatting it

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to replace every instance of ", that is between a < and a > with '.

So, you look for each " in your string, look behind for a <, and ahead for a >. The regex looks like:

```
(?<=\<[^<>]*)"(?=[^><]*\>)
```

So you could use

```
outputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, "(?<=\\<[^<>]*)\"(?=[^><]*\\>)", "'");
```

And then you want escape other " in your string. For that you could use

```
outputString = outputString.Replace(@"""", @"\""");
```

OR

```
outputString = outputString.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

I create a console application to test this ,

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter The String : ");
 string input = Console.ReadLine();          
 string pattern = "(?<=\\<[^<>]*)\"(?=[^><]*\\>)";
 string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "'");
 output = output.Replace(@"""", @"\""");
 Console.WriteLine(output);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Input string is the string you provided and then the output will be,

```
<p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing <span id= '#' ids= '#' display= 'inline' ></ span > and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever \"since the 1500s\".<br></p>
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but this expression is not working

Comment: I updated the answer with a example console app. Check that

Answer (score 0):

Better replace all double(") by (\"). This way you can store the double quote as a part of string.
Foe example :

```
string storeValue = "Subash \"Kharel\"";
```